# rs(1) prints all output in a single line; how to duplicate the input array shape?

Tags: shell-script, columns, rs

Consider this usage of [`rs(1)`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports):

```bash
rs -n -z -c, <<CSV
a,b,c
dd,ee,ff
CSV
```

The above snippet emits:

```
a  b  c  dd  ee  ff
```

But I was expecting to see something like this:

```
a   b   c
dd  ee  ff
```

The manual suggests that the output array shape should match the input array shape unless configured otherwise.

`rs -h` using the same input emits `2 3`, which suggests that `rs` does correctly identify the input array shape.

What am I misunderstanding in the usage of `rs`? Is there a way to have it automatically format the output with the same shape as the input?

Comment: It's an ugly hack, but doing a `-T` (pure transpose) then piping the result through a second `rs -T` seems to work for me

Comment: Not answering your `rs` question but `column -s, -t <<CSV ...` does what you want.

Comment: @glennjackman I had problems with `column` when a leading cell is "blank", which is how I found `rs` in the first place! I made a follow-up question about it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/733969/73256

Comment: Actually, `rs` has the same problem as `column` in that example! It's a little surprising that these basic tools behave so weirdly. I'm tempted to write my own AWK script and ignore all these.

Comment: `rs` is used to reshape data. It seems that you don't actually want to _reshape_ the data, which in turn means `rs` might be the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Kusalananda that's entirely possible! But it does seem like the docs and the implementation disagree with each other here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you see a disagreement. The only option that appears not to require specifying at _at least one_ of `rows` and `cols` is the `-T` option, which transposes the input.  All other options rely on the user specifying either `rows` or `cols` explicitly to reshape the data to that specification.

Answer (score 2):

column does not behave as expected with leading empty fields.
You might want this

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","; OFS = "\t"} {$1 = $1} 1' <<DATA
a,b,c
,x,y
dd,ee,ff
DATA
```

```
a   b   c
    x   y
dd  ee  ff
```