# column(1) drops blank leading cells; is it fixable?

Tags: shell-script, columns

Consider this usage of [column(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=column&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports):

```bash
column -s, -t <<CSV
a,b,c
,ee,ff
CSV
```

The above snippet emits:

```
a   b   c
ee  ff
```

But I was expecting to see something like this:

```
a   b   c
    ee  ff
```

`column` seems to be dropping the leading blank "cell" from the 2nd row, while I would expect and want it to be preserved.

Is there any way to disable this blank-stripping behavior in column? Are there any standard/recommended workaround suggestions?

I tried using [rs(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports), but I had other problems with that command: [rs(1) prints all output in a single line; how to duplicate the input array shape?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/733865/73256)

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: cannot reproduce. I get exactly your desired output.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: what version of column are you using?  I can reproduce it with BSD column.

Comment: `column --version`: `column from util-linux 2.38.1`

Answer (score 1):

The `column` utility removes empty columns from the start and end of each line.  This gives rise to the misaligned columns that you observe.  There are no options for the utility to disable this behaviour.

Would you want to convert a general CSV document to another format, such as TSV, a safer way would be to use a CSV-aware tool such as Miller:

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --otsv cat <<END_DATA
a,b,c,"d,e"
,ee,ff,"ok ""hello"""
END_DATA
a       b       c       d,e
        ee      ff      "ok ""hello"""
```

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --opprint cat <<END_DATA
a,b,c,"d,e"
,ee,ff,"ok ""hello"""
END_DATA
a b  c  d,e
- ee ff ok "hello"
```

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --opprint --barred cat <<END_DATA
a,b,c,"d,e"
,ee,ff,"ok ""hello"""
END_DATA
+---+----+----+------------+
| a | b  | c  | d,e        |
+---+----+----+------------+
| - | ee | ff | ok "hello" |
+---+----+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

You can use Raku's `Text::CSV` module: it will output RFC-4180 (and possibly RFC-4180/RFC-7111) conforming files. Needless to say, blank leading cells are retained. Below, output with a different column separator (tab) demonstrating:

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN); csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep => "\t");'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
a,b,c
,ee,ff
```

Sample Output (tab separated):

```
a   b   c
    ee  ff
```

See the link below if your file is huge and/or you want to read your CSV files linewise.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722776/227738
https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.pdf
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

If "non-standard" tools are OK, the [XSV toolkit](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) can nicely format more or less arbitrary delimited-text data:

```bash
xsv table <<CSV
a,b,c
,ee,ff
CSV
```

```
a   b   c
    ee  ff
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is "simple CSV", with no quoted commas or newlines, so that a comma can only occur to separate fields, you could use `awk` to get the effect you want:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$1=$1; print}' <<CSV
a,b,c
,ee,ff
CSV
```

Output

```
a       b       c
        ee      ff
```